# What is the quickest way to get Void Salts in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The other day I got the Nightingale armour and I have a pretty high smithing skill but I need Void Salts to upgrade the nightingale armour. Any suggestions?
I've tried looking at alchemy shops, my houses (Proudspire Manor, Hjerim and Honeyside), but none are there.

Comment: You need Void Salts to do what?

Answer (score 2):

There is an overview on [fandom.com](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Void_Salts_(Skyrim)) of **places where you can find Void Salts**:

> - Looted from Storm Atronachs.
> - Can be very rarely looted from Falmer.
> - Can be bought from alchemist's shops.
> - Proudspire Manor alchemy lab in Solitude.
> - Honeyside alchemy lab in Riften.
> - Hjerim alchemy lab in Windhelm.
> - Arch-Mage's Quarters in the College of Winterhold.
> - Arcadia's Cauldron in Whiterun, on a shelf.
> - Fletcher in Solitude, on a shelf.
> - May be found in apothecary's satchels.
> - May be awarded by Narfi at the end of his quest "The Straw that Broke."
> - Can be obtained at Sky Haven Temple.
> - Can be stolen in Calixto's House of Curiosities in Windhelm.
> - In Sadri's Used Wares in Windhelm, on the shelves. He also sells this sample.
> - 1 can be found in Valerica's Study in Castle Volkihar.
> - On a shelf inside of Ragnvald Temple.

Note that this was the first hit when googling for 'Void Salts' - that was the 'quickest way' to get them. In-game, it depends on your character, and is therefore hard to answer.